# coverage3 run OMIT libraries

Tags: python, python-3.x, code-coverage, coverage.py

I'm running `coverage3 run` and I want to omit the libraries, `numpy` and `requests`.

When I do `coverage3 run --omit=*numpy*` it omits the numpy library, however when I do `coverage3 run --omit='*requests*, *numpy*'` it only omits the first one, which is `requests` and doesn't omit `numpy` also.

How do I omit more than 1 libraries when I'm running coverage3?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the answer might be as simple as leaving out the extra space.  Instead of:

```
coverage3 run --omit='*requests*, *numpy*'
```

use:

```
coverage3 run --omit='*requests*,*numpy*'
```

Though you shouldn't that many stars either...

Comment: BTW: it seems silly for coverage.py to care about that space, so I wrote this issue: https://bitbucket.org/ned/coveragepy/issues/413/comma-separate-options-should-be-less